# ASP.Net Core 2 Web API performance metrics in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to store each request's in-time, out-time, api in a database context managed by Entity Framework.

Best approach seemed to add a middleware at the entry point. I could get up to the point of collecting the metrics and api, but could not put in database as EF DBContext seems to be tied to Mvc layer. It was giving me a ObjectDisposedException.

`Q1: Is this something we can put to work?`

So, I was willing to put up with the next best option of moving it to Filter. The first point of entry into Mvc seems to be Authorization filter. But I don't see how to get OnExecuting and OnExecuted events in this filter. I am able to store everything in the database in the filter, though.

`Q2: How do I get the in-time and out-time in AuthorizationFilter?`

`Q3: A more elaborate solution would be to put the metrics into ElasticSearch or an external system. But how to ensure we have a connection pool (or equivalent) wired up and ready for use at the middleware entry point. Would it not suffer the same issue as DBContext?`

Answer (score 1):

> Q3: A more elaborate solution would be to put the metrics into
>   ElasticSearch or an external system. But how to ensure we have a
>   connection pool (or equivalent) wired up and ready for use at the
>   middleware entry point. Would it not suffer the same issue as
>   DBContext?

I would recommend using Serilog with appropriate sink (e.g. [ElasticSearch](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch)). You can configure it on app startup, integrate it to host with `UseSerilog` and after that you can easily inject it to the middleware (or filter) using standard `ILogger` interface (or using Serilog explicitly, e.g. `Log.ForContext<YourMiddleware>()`)

Comment: Ok. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You mention streaming metrics to an external system, so its worth suggesting adding [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-core) to your application. Combined with the portal, it's a very powerful tool, especially the [analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics) functionality. There is also a free tier iirc.

I dont work for MS etc, so I'm not pushing a product, just a suggestion.